# Make only one legend active in HighCharts at the start

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I got success in getting the data from JSON File in HighCharts. But the only problem is I need only one legend to be active at the start...Any help will be Appreciated....

```
For getting Data
 for(let i=0;i<datae.dataa.length;i++)
              {
                chart.series[i].setName(datae.dataa[i].name);
                chart.series[i].setData(datae.dataa[i].data);        
              }
```

Present Output: [image]
Required Output: [image: Only one legend to be highlighted at start]
I am not good at HighCharts so please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`Series.setVisible`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setVisible). E.g. `chart.series[i].setVisible(false)`.

Or use [`visible` member of series data](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.visible) when creating a chart.